# How to set Appium to take screenshots on every action

Tags: java, selenium, appium

Is there any possible way to set to take screenshots on every actions in Appium level not from code level.

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood is that you want to capture screenshot whenever there is an operation performed on real device (like click, sendkeys, touch, swipe, etc). For this you can create a user defined method takeScreenShot() and make a call to it whenever you need to capture a screenshot.

Code goes like this :

```
public void takeScreenShot() {
//Set folder name to store screenshots.
destDir = "screenshots";
// Capture screenshot.
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
// Set date format to set It as screenshot file name.
dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy__hh_mm_ssaa");
// Create folder under project with name "screenshots" provided to destDir.
new File(destDir).mkdirs();
// Set file name using current date time.
String destFile = dateFormat.format(new Date()) + ".png";
```

Comment: Go through the above mentioned link. Inside each event listener method can invoke the takeScreenShot(). I guess this might help you out.